# UWP Accessing content in a data bound ListView

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a ListView with a ListView.ItemTemplate if it is important: the ListView is part of a Grid). I will strip it down here for the minumum:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstFotos" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="auto"  Tapped="imageControl_Tapped" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image x:Name="imageControl" Width="200" Height="200" Source="{Binding DateiSoftwareBitmapSource}" IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"  />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtImageDateDescription" Text="Aufnahmedatum: " Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtImageDescriptionDescription" Text="Beschreibung: " Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtImageDate" Text="{Binding Datum}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtImageDescription" Text="{Binding Beschreibung}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                <Button x:Name="btnSpeichern" Content="Speichern" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Click="btnSpeichern_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the code behing I do a

```
lstFotos.ItemsSource = AlleAnzeigeFotos
```

AlleAnzeigeFotos is a List(Of myClass), myClass contains the properties *Datum, Beschreibung, DateiSoftwareBitmapSource*.

What I want to do is that the user can edit the textfield, presses on the button and in the code behing I want to update the class and do some more stuff.

How can I get the appropriate instance of that class when I click the button?

UPDATE:
This is how it looks like:
[image]

"Beschreibung" (english: description) is empy after adding a foto and should be editable and stored by clicking "Speichern" (save).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(sender as Button).DataContext` will give you the item which you clicked. Cast it to appropriate type of your class

**update**

```
Text="{Binding Beschreibung,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 

var userenteredstring=((sender as Button).DataContext as your class).Beschreibung
```

Comment: That is very easy and well explained. Thank you!

Comment: But: I need to get the text in the Textbox the user entered to store it in the property 'Beschreibung' - how do I get that?

Comment: You have to bind with TwoWay binding  and updatesourcetrigger should be propertychanged.check the update

Comment: Ok, using your additional information I now get the value of my Textbox. What I do not understand is how to store that value in my class. All instances of my class are displayed in the ListView and I want to enter or change a (string-) value (Beschreibung), press the button and the property is updated.

Comment: Its already stored in Beschreibung property. You dont need to do anything

Comment: Ok, thank you VERY much - it is much easier than I expected. It works now and is my solution.